# WCAG 2.0: Technique H65 and hidden form controls

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag

The Technique [H65](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-WCAG20-TECHS-20081103/H65) should be used even if I have an hidden form control? 
For example:

1) input type="hidden"

2) input hidden by css

Comment: What do you mean by *hidden* in CSS? `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` (hidden from AT also, then the problem may be with desactivating CSS and perceiving completely different things) or displayed out of the viewport (like `left: -9999px`: still perceived by ATs and why on earth an `input[type="text"]` may be read out *only* to screen readers?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It isn't an interactive control, so no.
2. It depends on the context.

   - If it is always hidden, why is it hidden with CSS instead of being `type=hidden`?
   - If it is hidden some of the time, then it is no different from any other control and you should use a `<label>` if you can. You can hide the label when you hide the control. H65 is very much a last resort for when the designer can't be convinced to produce an accessible design. Use it if you should use a `<label>` but aren't allowed to fix the design.

Comment: 1) Ok, Thanks!

2) Some webdesigners/developers sometimes hide <input type="text"> tags throught css. It isn't nice, but it happens!

Comment: 1) Yep, it isn't displayed by browsers (even without CSS) or perceived by ATs 2) +1